# Match 2 arrays in php

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-url

My two array values are

1)

```
Array (
               [0] => School Children 
               [1] => Vocational Training Centre
               [2] => Admission Fee
          )
```

2) Admission Fee

```
Array (
              [0] => School Children
              [1] => World Ten K
              [2] => Vocational Training Centre
              [3] => Van travel
              [4] => Admission Fee
        )
```

Here their keys are different, if both are mathing only my check box is checked otherwise they are not checked.

I have tried by using `array_search` but no use and also some cases `in_array`.

`$main` for all the values and `$temp_imp` are the values coming from the database

```
<?php 
    $i=0;

    foreach($prj_data as $prj_pop){
        $main[]=$prj_pop->name;
?>
    <br/><br/>
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox_project" value="<?php echo  $prj_pop->name;?>"
<?php 
        if (array_intersect($temp_imp, $main))
        {
            echo 'checked="true"';
        } 
?>
<?php
        echo $prj_pop->name;
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: can you rephrase the question?

Comment: What are you even asking?

Comment: There should be a condition like checking with the names not with the keys

Comment: What condition, checking for what?

Comment: You need to go into much more detail. What do these 2 arrays represent, and what do you want to output? Target me in a comment using @AdiBradfield when you make an edit, and I'll come back and try to help you

Answer (score 0):

Ohhhh think I've finally got my head around what your asking! You want to do something like this:

```
<?php
foreach($array1 as $a){
    if( in_array($a, $array2))){
        //Value in both

    }
    else{
        //Value only in 1st array   
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple function to see if one array's values match another array's values. In this case, it returns `TRUE` if all `$array1` values are present in `$array2`, or `FALSE` if it finds a value from `$array1` that is not in `$array2`.

```
function array_match($array1, $array2) {
  foreach ($array1 as $value) {
    if (!in_array($value, $array2)) {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want to check for equality:

```
$array1 = array(
    'School Children',
    'Vocational Training Centre',
    'Admission Fee'
);

$array2 = array(
    'School Children',
    'World Ten K',
    'Vocational Training Centre',
    'Van travel',
    'Admission Fee'
);

sort($array1);
sort($array2);

if (md5(serialize($array1)) === md5(serialize($array2))) {
    echo 'equal';
}
else {
    echo 'not equal';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you want an array with the values in the given arrays, you can use `array_intersect()` , because this array has "no keys", but only values.

Answer (score 0):

simplest way is to use  array_intersect php function and check the result: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php